# Java Throws ExecutionException in a loop after several successful thread executions

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

I'm having trouble with the callable thread.

Here is code snipet:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);  
for(int i =0; i<30;i++){  
    Future<MyClass> task = service.submit( new MyThread(parameter1, parameter2));  
    try{  
        result = task.get();  
    }  
    catch(InterruptedException ex){  
        System.out.println("Interruped!");  
    }  
    catch(ExecutionException ex){  
        System.out.println("Execution ExceptioN!");  
    }  
}  
service.shutdownNow();
```

The code above would correctly executes 18 times and then throw the ExecutionException after the 18th time.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure: `MyThread` implements `Callable` and has nothing to do with (does not extend) `Thread`?

Answer (score 5):

ExecutionException documentation states:

**Exception thrown when attempting to retrieve the result of a task that aborted by throwing an exception. This exception can be inspected using the Throwable.getCause() method.**

So your task is throwing an exception.  Call getCause on the ExecutionException to view that exception.